# Check if a draw function exists in a Menu before registering

Tags: python, scripting, interface

How can I check if a draw function exists in a Menu before registering? When I write prototypes in the Text Editor, I get multiple draw functions added in Blender's UI.

```py
def menu_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    # draw code here

def register():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)
```

Though it has an `append` method, `bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object` is of type  `bpy_types.RNAMeta` and is not iterable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by [this post](https://blenderartists.org/t/menu-item-cant-be-removed/1419929/2), I am iterating through `bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object._dyn_ui_initialize()` and comparing it to my draw function's name. If it doesn't exist, I'm appending it to the Menu:

```py
def object_menu(self, context):
    self.layout.label(text="Test")

def register():
    omenu = next(iter([f for f in bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object._dyn_ui_initialize() if f.__name__ == object_menu.__name__]),None)
    if not omenu:
        bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(object_menu)
```

Comment: Interesting. Although I would be wary of using it in production code, the underscore clearly indicates you shouldn't use that function outside of the class itself :) But it does solve the problem of stacking UI elements in prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

To remove appended functions from menus (when addon gets deactivated) and to avoid double entries I prefer to check `class.draw`.
If any function was appended to a class there´s the new attribute `_draw_funcs` in class.draw that we can use to check all appended functions

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "check appended",
    "blender": (2, 83, 1),
}

import bpy

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.label(text="lorem ipsum...")
    # draw code here

def register():
    cls = bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object 
    search = "menu_func"  
    
    # check if '_draw_funcs' in cls
    if hasattr(cls.draw, "_draw_funcs"): 

        # check if function name in '_draw_funcs'
        if [f for f in cls.draw._draw_funcs if f.__name__ == search]:
            print("function '%s' is already appended to %s" % (search, cls))
        else:
            bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)  # append
            print("function '%s' was appended to %s" % (search, cls))                 

    else:  # no '_draw_funcs' in cls
        bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)   # append
        print("function '%s' was appended to %s" % (search, cls))          

def unregister():
    cls = bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object
    search = "menu_func"  
    if hasattr(cls.draw, "_draw_funcs") and [f for f in cls.draw._draw_funcs if f.__name__ == search]: # oneliner
        cls.remove(menu_func)         
        print("function '%s' was removed from %s" % (search, cls))  
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

to examine:

```
print(dir(bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.draw))

if hasattr(bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.draw, "_draw_funcs"): # last item

    # functions        
    print(bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.draw._draw_funcs)

    # functions by name
    for idx, func in enumerate(bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.draw._draw_funcs):
        print("function[%s]" % idx, func.__name__)
```